# Knockout edit table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I recently started learning knockout. I was given an assignment that requires me to get a JSON from a .txt file and then to make a table using knockout . The table should also be editable(add,remove and edit rows). I managed to do everything but the editing part. I would appreciate it if you guys could help me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="scripts/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="scripts/libs/jquery.shorten.1.0.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Num</th><th>isActive</th><th>Balance</th><th>Age</th><th>Eye Color</th><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Tags</th><th>Total</th><th>Company</th><th>email</th><th>phone</th><th>address</th><th>about</th><th>registered</th><th>greeting</th><th>favoriteFruit</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: People">
            <tr>
                <td> <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span></td>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isActive" /></td>
                <td ><span class="balanceRes" data-bind="text: $data.balance"></span></td>
                <td ><input class="balanceEdit" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.balance" /></td>
                <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: eyeColor"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: name.first"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: name.last"></td>
                <td><select data-bind="options: tags"></select></td>
                <td data-bind="text: range"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: company"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: phone"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
                <td class="about" data-bind="text: about"></td>
                <td class="date" name=data data-bind="text: registered"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: greeting"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: favoriteFruit"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="remove" data-bind="click:$parent.removePerson" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="edit" data-bind="click:$parent.editPerson" /></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
       Balance <input id="balance-add" type="text">
       Age <input id="age-add" type="text">
       Eye Color <input id="eyeColor-add" type="text">
       First Name <input id="firstName-add" type="text">
       Last Name <input id="lastName-add" type="text">
       Tags <input id="tags-add" type="text">
       Total <input id="total-add" type="text">
       Company <input id="company-add" type="text">
       Email <input id="email-add" type="text">
       Phone <input id="phone-add" type="text">
       Address <input id="address-add" type="text">
       About <input id="about-add" type="text">
       Registered <input type="text" name="date" id="date-add"/>
       Greeting <input id="greeting-add" type="text">
       Favorite Fruit <input id="fruit-add" type="text">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function () {
let dataText;
$.ajax({
    url : "scripts/data.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        dataText=data;
        var objJs=JSON.parse(dataText);
        var count = Object.keys(objJs).length;
        var sum=0;
        for(let i=0;i<count;i++){
            let ranges=objJs[i].range.length;
            for(let j=0;j<ranges;j++){
                sum+=objJs[i].range[j];
            }
            objJs[i].range=sum;
            sum=0;
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(objJs));
        createTable();
    }
})});

function createTable() {
$('#date-add').datepicker({ minDate: 0});
$('.about').shorten({
    "showChars" : 50
});}

function AppViewModel(data) {
let self=this;
self.People=ko.observableArray(data);
self.addPerson=function() {
    self.People.push({isActive:false, balance:$('#balance-add').val(),age:$('#age-add').val(),eyeColor: $('#eyeColor-add').val(),
        name:{first:$('#firstName-add').val(),last:$('#lastName-add').val()}, tags:$('#tags-add').val().split(","),
        range:$('#total-add').val(),company:$('#company-add').val(),email:$('#email-add').val(),email:$('#email-add').val(),
        phone:$('#phone-add').val(),address:$('#address-add').val(),address:$('#address-add').val(),about:$('#about-add').val(),
        registered:$('#date-add').val(),greeting:$('#greeting-add').val(),favoriteFruit:$('#fruit-add').val()})}
self.removePerson=function (people) {
    self.People.remove(people);
}
self.editPerson=function (people) {

}}
```

I am currently trying to make it so that when the edit button is pressed ,the span with the balance value gets updated from the input next to it.The problem is that I don't know how to do the self.editPerson=function(people)  function properly.
I tried with this.People.balance(index.balance); -(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined) or self.People()[people.index].balance=people.balance; -(no result or error)
Every other thing i tried was without success.
During debugging i saw that self.People()[people.index].balance is already changed with the value from the input field after the edit button click event,but it doesn't get displayed in the table.
Any ideas how i can display it in the table?

here is some of the content in the txt file:

```
  [{
    "_id": "5608ef7db3723785000cc555",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "fc4c666f-3da1-4627-899b-a79fea0901cd",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,288.11",
    "age": 22,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Brandie",
      "last": "Mathis"
    },
    "company": "XEREX",
    "email": "brandie.mathis@xerex.com",
    "phone": "+1 (975) 575-2608",
    "address": "728 Colonial Road, Neibert, South Dakota, 7145",
    "about": "Ad pariatur aute adipisicing magna enim nulla laboris. Sunt officia consequat elit fugiat ipsum sint aliquip sit irure sunt quis laboris. Labore elit consectetur excepteur ex in velit quis mollit excepteur aute nostrud cupidatat sint. Veniam labore incididunt exercitation mollit veniam et consequat mollit dolore do. Laboris ad proident et culpa irure et ullamco qui fugiat labore ex voluptate culpa. Laboris nisi sunt magna et.",
    "registered": "Tuesday, August 5, 2014 3:53 PM",
    "tags": [
      "deserunt",
      "do",
      "sint",
      "proident",
      "nulla",
      "Lorem",
      "esse",
      "custom_tag"
    ],
    "range": [
      1,
      3,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      7,
      8
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Brandie! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5608ef7d5503c0da99a874ae",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "5ca9f2f0-a2bf-4ba5-be84-40df2020c7e6",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,205.31",
    "age": 20,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Celia",
      "last": "Hopper"
    },
    "company": "QUANTALIA",
    "email": "celia.hopper@quantalia.ca",
    "phone": "+1 (899) 588-2155",
    "address": "488 Monaco Place, Abrams, Oklahoma, 4175",
    "about": "Magna ut cillum nisi ipsum tempor aute. Mollit exercitation voluptate cillum anim sit laborum qui ullamco occaecat culpa in. Consequat eu qui sint exercitation magna ea proident excepteur ullamco velit nisi. Ullamco ullamco anim cillum Lorem ea mollit do minim. Ad nisi dolor consectetur anim nisi ex ea elit ullamco nostrud nisi id.",
    "registered": "Saturday, January 3, 2015 10:56 PM",
    "tags": [
      "deserunt",
      "do",
      "sint",
      "proident",
      "nulla",
      "Lorem",
      "esse",
      "custom_tag"
    ],
    "range": [
      0,
      1,
      3,
      4,
      6,
      7,
      9
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Celia! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "strawberry"
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

The current data context is passed to the `click` handler. Within your `foreach`, the data context is the current row, which is exactly what you want. I've made a greatly simplified example to demonstrate.

Also: don't pull values from the form for your `addPerson`. Those inputs should be value-bound to items in your viewmodel. Any communication between your viewmodel and the form must be brokered by Knockout.

```js
vm = {
  people: [{
    name: 'One',
    age: 1
  }, {
    name: 'Two',
    age: 2
  }],
  editor: {
    name: ko.observable(),
    age: ko.observable()
  },
  editPerson: function (data) {
    vm.editor.name(data.name);
    vm.editor.age(data.age);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:people">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.editPerson">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div data-bind="with: editor">
  <div>Name:
    <input data-bind="value:name" />
  </div>
  <div>Age:
    <input data-bind="value:age" />
  </div>
</div>
```